# Doesn't load parent Js files in ng-view AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have created single page application using Angular.I have navigation panel for the app that load different views(html) into my main parent html.My parent nav tab something like this.

**Sample code snippet**

```
<html>
<head>
//I have loaded nessasary js and css files here
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
     </ul>
<div id="main"  >

       <!-- Load html templates here -->
        <div ng-view>

        </div>
        </div>

//Those files doesn't load in my template files
        <script src="libs/typeahead/dist/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/tokenfield/dist/bootstrap-tokenfield.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Sample about.html**

```
<div>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    //My content here
    </div>
</div>
```

when about nav tab click it load the about.html into the ng-view.My routing is working fine.but the problem was that.i have some js files that common to both html files.(home and about html).so i put those common files inside the parent html after ng-view.so after my about.html file and other template files load into ng-view js files in parent html functions doesn't execute.also when go back to another view loaded js files also missing but when page refresh they work well.

Please let me know how can i load parent Js files inside template files.

Comment: Can you be more clearly? I don't understand you.

Comment: @Olga Akhmetova i edit the post.please have a look.

Comment: are there any error in console? if include js files in `<head>` section, they also not working?

Comment: yes it doesnt work even include in `<head>` section.console shows me some js files functions are missing.not defined.

Comment: Does it work in another browsers? I don't have many idea what is the problem. Because after refresh all work, issue may be in order of script loading. Try load this scripts before all your scripts.

Comment: @Olga Akhmetova i didnt try another browsers.i will try.Thank for your concern.